# My swf is not downloaded to my android app from server AS3 air issue

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, shared-hosting

I am trying to make an `Android` app using air
the app has a link to download swf that is hosted on my godaddy shared hosting then the code put the swf on my android device to work.

When I put the swf on `Google` shared hosting, it is not working and the swf is not downloaded.

But when I test the same app after putting the swf on a dedicated server with security options permit to read and write on the hosting folder, it works while folder read/write permission is not permitted on `Google` shared hosting

Are there any solution to make the code works with read only permission on the shared hosting and why the needed read/write permission?

Thank you.!!

Here is my code:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
                urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.*****.com/******.swf"));
                urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
                urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_handler);
                function complete_handler(event:Event):void
                {

                if (status.text == "100%")
                {
                    ss.gotoAndStop(1);
                    loading.visible = false;
                    status.visible = false;
                    Success1.gotoAndPlay(2);
                    btn1.alpha = 1;
                    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,clickM);
                }

                var data:ByteArray = event.target.data;
                var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("*****/"+"*****.swf");
                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
                fileStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length);
            }
```

Comment: Why are you using external swf's? What code do you have in them? In general, you're not supposed to use external swfs and you don't need to.

Comment: I am using external swfs to save my apk file size to not be too large as I don't know how to add them as resources into google play store